# Cordova - write to and read from File

Tags: ios, cordova

I am running into a problem with my cordova app where after an app update, localStorage is cleared.  I am now attempting to save some basic user data to a text file instead, using cordova's FileWriter and FileReader.

At some point cordova updated and these methods and now requires a plugin to read and write files: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/index.html

Because my live iOS application uses the old version of cordova, it must write with FileWriter. My app update (not live) uses a newer version of cordova and therefore must use the plugin.

**------ Possible workaround found, see update below ------**

When trying to read the file, I am seeing the following error in xcode:

> 017-01-26 17:58:52.990 MyApp[40355:2892997] ERROR: Method 'hello there' not defined in Plugin 'File'
>   2017-01-26 17:58:52.991 MyApp[40355:2892997] -[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 142] FAILED pluginJSON = ["File1875336264","File","hello there",["cdvfile://localhost/persistent/player_data.txt",null,null]]

Note: I'm running the following code in Safari console while the iOS simulator is running, just for convenience

My code for writing the file

```
(function() {
var onFail = function(err) {
    alert('write action failed!');
    alert(err.code);
};

var onGotFS = function(fileSystem) {
    alert( 'gotFS' );
    fileSystem.root.getFile("player_data.txt", {create: true}, onGotFileEntry, onFail);
};

var onGotFileEntry = function(fileEntry) {
     alert( 'gotFileEntry, path: ' + fileEntry.fullPath );
     fileEntry.createWriter(onGotFileWriter, onFail);
};

var onGotFileWriter = function(writer) {
    alert( 'gotFileWriter' );
    writer.onwrite = onFileWritten;
    writer.onerror = onFail;

    var data = "hello there";
    alert( 'writing data: ' + data );
    writer.write( data );
};

var onFileWritten = function(evt) {
    alert( "saveTokenToFile SUCCESS!" );
};

// start process of looking up file system and writing
alert( 'requesting file system ...' );
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 1024, onGotFS, onFail);
```

})();

My code for reading the file:

```
(function() {
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fs) {
    fs.root.getFile("player_data.txt", { create: true }, function (fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.file(function (file) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = function() {
                alert("Success");
                console.log(evt.target.result);
            };

            reader.onerror = function() {
                console.log("reader error");                
            };

            reader.readAsText(file);
        }, onErrorReadFile);
    });
}, onErrorLoadFs);

var onErrorReadFile = function(){
    console.log("error reading file");
}

var onErrorLoadFs = function() {
    console.log("request file system has failed to load.");
}
```

})();

**UPDATE**

In case anyone else runs into this, I did find a way to read the saved file.  The fileEntry object has a URL path to the saved file. To access the data on the file, I'm passing that URL to jQuery.getJSON, which gives us back some readable json.

```
    readDataFromFile: function(){
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fs) {
        fs.root.getFile("player_data.txt", {}, function (fileEntry) {
            var entryURL = fileEntry.nativeURL;
            jQuery.getJSON(entryURL, function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }).fail(function(){
                console.log("file found, but contents were empty");
            });
        }, onErrorGetFile);
    }, onErrorLoadFs);

    var onErrorLoadFs = function() {
        console.log("request file system has failed to load.");
    };

    var onErrorGetFile = function() {
        console.log("requested file can not be read or does not exist");
    };
}
```

Comment: thanks @bob-M - this is exactly what I was needing!!!!